# array of size 2 - if one of the elements is empty, set it equal to the other

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm building out a alphabetical range picker.  So, you pick `["A", "D"]`, and it will look for contacts whose last names start with A, B, C , and D.

But, if you only pick `["A", ""]` or `["", "D"]`, then I want to just return `["A", "A"]` or `["D", "D"]`.

Is there an alternative to writing the following:

```
const lookup = letters;

if (letters[0] === '' && letters[1] !== '') {
  lookup[0] = letters[1];
}
if (letters[0] !== '' && letters[1] === '') {
  lookup[1] = letters[0];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're mixing `lookup` and `letters`? They both reference the same array.

Answer (score 1):

You could condense the logic a little.

```
const lookup = ['A', ''];

lookup[0] = lookup[0] || lookup[1];
lookup[1] = lookup[1] || lookup[0];

console.log(lookup);
```

Comment: In real life code, make sure `letters` is declared beforehand, because initializing variables like this implicitly creates `letters` as a global variable instead of a local `const`.

Comment: @4castle, thanks for the feedback. I didn't realise that. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the array and if the current value is empty, set it to either the next element value, the previous element value or `''`.

```js
let arr1 = ['A', ''];
let arr2 = ['', 'D'];
let arr3 = ['A', 'D'];
let arr4 = ['', ''];

function fix(arr) {
  return arr.map((cv, idx, ar) => cv === '' ? ar[idx + 1] || ar[idx - 1] || '' : cv);
}

console.log(fix(arr1));
console.log(fix(arr2));
console.log(fix(arr3));
console.log(fix(arr4));
```